# Sum columns of two pandas dataframes of different sizes only for certain rows

Tags: python, pandas, sum

I have two pandas dataframes looking like:

```
df1:
      n  column1
0   5.0      0.0
1   6.0      0.0
2   7.0      0.0
3   8.0      0.0
4   9.0      0.0
5  10.0      0.0

df2:
     n  column2
0  6.0      1.0
1  7.0      1.0
2  8.0      1.0
```

I want to sum `column1` and `column2` only for rows where **n** is the same. Desired output looks like:

```
df3:
      n  column1
0   5.0      0.0
1   6.0      1.0
2   7.0      1.0
3   8.0      1.0
4   9.0      0.0
5  10.0      0.0
```

Please note that:

- Values of **n** may vary from one case to another so I can't fill the columns of `df2` with zeroes and perform a classical sum.
- Values of **n** should not be modified in the end. So I'd like to avoid work-arounds like shifting **n** values to make them match with rows indexes.
- What I've tried so far produces something like:

  ```
        n  column1
  0   5.0      1.0
  1   6.0      1.0
  2   7.0      1.0
  3   8.0      NaN
  4   9.0      NaN
  5  10.0      NaN
  ```

  Because sum is by default performed based on row's indexes in common rather than on **n** as I wish.

How can I perform this with pandas built-in functions ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Series.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.add.html), but first create indexes from columns `n` by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df = (df2.set_index('n')['column2']
         .add(df1.set_index('n')['column1'], fill_value=0)
         .reset_index(name='column1'))
print (df)
      n  column1
0   5.0      0.0
1   6.0      1.0
2   7.0      1.0
3   8.0      1.0
4   9.0      0.0
5  10.0      0.0
```

Another solution with [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and left join:

```
df = (df1.merge(df2, on='n', how='left'))
df['column1'] = df['column2'].add(df['column1'], fill_value=0)
df = df.drop('column2', axis=1)
print (df)
      n  column1
0   5.0      0.0
1   6.0      1.0
2   7.0      1.0
3   8.0      1.0
4   9.0      0.0
5  10.0      0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

i solved it by merging the dataframe and sum it on pandas:

`df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', on='n')`

`df['sum'] = df['column1'] + df['column2']`

`df[['n', 'sum']].fillna(0)`

the result looks like this:

```
    n   sum
0   5.0 0.0
1   6.0 1.0
2   7.0 1.0 
3   8.0 1.0
4   9.0 0.0
5   10.0    0.0
```